# How to set up routetable correctly to direct URL to controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routetable

In MVC 5 application, I want to accept two different kinds of request URL:

1. `http://www.myapp.com/brand/controller/action`
2. `http://www.myapp.com/controller/action`

Both URL should be directed to controller action.

I tried to include optional parameter brand in it, but no luck.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "default",
    "{brand}/{controller}/{action}",
    new { brand = UrlParameter.Optional, controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Apparently optional parameter is not allowed before controller.

Any idea?

Comment: A `UrlParameter.Optional` can only be applied to the last segment. You would need 2 route definitions `{brand}/{controller}/{action}` (where `brand` is not optional) and `{controller}/{action}` but then you would need a constraint on the first route so that if `brand` is not one of a set of predefined values it would then match the 2nd route

Comment: What is `brand` and what are its possible values?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment, Stephen.

What I want is to inject optional parameter brand into URL, brand should be some string values, but here I want to ignore it and direct to correct controller action.

Well, I found one function that might be useful for this case:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

But the thing is I have to put Route attribute for each controller action, like:

```
  public class LoginController : Controller
  {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/{brand}/Login")]
    [Route("~/Login")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }
  }
```

Maybe I need to find some examples how to use attribute routes.